# How to make ViewModels common in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I make Email Magazine Form by Vue.js. There are four independent forms in one view(html). For forms are the same.(Implememts are the same.) But each form uses diefferent data, so I had to make ViewModel four times, changing the `el`. I think its kind of lengthy, I dont want to make ViewModel four times, I want it only once. Does anyone know any good idea to simplize this implementation? Thank you.

```
    class @Article.EmailMagazine

      constructor: () ->

      render: (tag)->
        new Vue
          el: "#email_magazine_registration_" + tag,
          data:
            registration: true
            email: null
            errors:
              email: false
            messages: []
          methods:
            build_refresh: ->
              @errors.email = false
              @messages = []
            validate_before: ->
              ...
            validate_after: (message)->
              ...
            cancel: ->
              @registration = false
            save: ->
              @validate_before()
              return if @errors.email
              $.ajax
                async: true
                type: 'POST'
                dataType: 'json'
                url: '/user_email_magazines'
                data:
                    email: @email
                context: this
                success: (data) ->
                  @registration = false
                error: (data) ->
                  @validate_after(data.responseJSON[0])
    $ ->
      if $('body').hasClass('articles')
        top = new Article.EmailMagazine()
        top.render('top')
        nav = new Article.EmailMagazine()
        nav.render('nav')
        side = new Article.EmailMagazine()
        side.render('side')
        under = new Article.EmailMagazine()
        under.render('under')
```

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to apply Vue to already rendered HTML. Components require a template or render function, so they cannot be applied the same way a Vue can. In your case, creating four Vues is probably fine.